# Issue with using get() in R - object is not found (might be related to environment?)

Tags: r

after learning so much by searching for answers on Stack OverFlow, I'm sharing my first question in the hope someone can help me. In the end, I plan to write a more complex function but I already condensed it to this issue, which I think is related to variable allocation / variable environment in R.

What I try to do, basically, is to set a variable name based on a string, so I can pass it over to the function (and use it as a parameter in another subordinate function). Therefore, I try to use the `get()` function. However, in the end, I always get the `Error in get(xyz) : object 'xyz' not found`.
I feel like the solution shouldn't be that difficult and that I miss something obvious, but after various attempts described below, I'm stuck.

But let's start from the beginning. This is what I want to do and it works fine when used in the Console/ Global Environment (please keep in mind, that this is a condensed version, I obviously wouldn't create a function just for that):

```
lapply(mi.list, FUN = function(dat) {
    xyzabc <- "WeightResp_BL_Full"
    stats::lm(Burden_Amount_BL ~ Akzeptanz_3_BL_r, data = dat, weight=get(xyzabc))
})
[Correct Output]
```

I am also able to recreate the same functionality when I hard-write it into the function like this:

```
condensed_f <- function (mi.list, formula) 
{   lapply(mi.list, FUN = function(dat) {
        stats::lm(formula, data = dat, weight=get("WeightResp_BL_Full"))
    })}
condensed_f (mi.list=mi.list, formula="Burden_Amount_BL ~ Akzeptanz_3_BL_r")
[Correct Output]
```

However, when I try to assign the string to a variable and use `get(xyz)`, I get the error message that the `object 'xyz' [is] not found`:

```
condensed_f <- function (mi.list, formula) 
{   lapply(mi.list, FUN = function(dat) {
        xyz <- "WeightResp_BL_Full"
        print(xyz)
        stats::lm(formula, data = dat, weight=get(xyz))
    })}
condensed_f (mi.list=mi.list, formula="Burden_Amount_BL ~ Akzeptanz_3_BL_r")

[1] "WeightResp_BL_Full"
 Error in get(xyz) : object 'xyz' not found
```

As you can see through the printout, `xyz` is accessible there, yet it isn't able to be found when used in the `lm()`-function. At the same time, however, there is no issue with the `formula` variable.

The issue persists when I define `xyz` in the same way I define `formula`:

```
condensed_f <- function (mi.list, formula, xyz="WeightResp_BL_Full") 
{   lapply(mi.list, FUN = function(dat) {
        print(xyz)
        stats::lm(formula, data = dat, weight=get(xyz))
    })}
condensed_f (mi.list=mi.list, formula="Burden_Amount_BL ~ Akzeptanz_3_BL_r")

[1] "WeightResp_BL_Full"
 Error in get(xyz) : object 'xyz' not found 

condensed_f <- function (mi.list, formula, xyz) 
{   lapply(mi.list, FUN = function(dat) {
        print(xyz)
        stats::lm(formula, data = dat, weight=get(xyz))
    })}
condensed_f (mi.list=mi.list, formula="Burden_Amount_BL ~ Akzeptanz_3_BL_r", xyz="WeightResp_BL_Full")

[1] "WeightResp_BL_Full"
 Error in get(xyz) : object 'xyz' not found
```

I, therefore, tried to debug it and went step-by-step into the underlying functions. What I discovered is, that `formula` is used relatively early after `lm()` is called, whereas the `weight`-parameter is used later.
That's why I presume that this might be related to the environment where R searches for the `xyz` object, So I played around with the `envir` parameter: `get(xyz, envir=environment())` and `get(xyz, envir=parent.env())`, yet the same issue persisted.

Maybe it isn't even related to the environment and using the `get()` function is the wrong way to go here. I also tried to resolve the string with `eval(parse(xyz))` but wasn't having any luck there.

Maybe someone out there sees this is finds the (obvious?) solution? I would really appreciate the help.

**Edit1**: I realized that it might be helpful to clarify the structure of mi.list and its related variables.
I have a dataset of several hundred people containing, among others's the variables `Burden_Amount_BL`, `Akzeptanz_3_BL_r`, and `WeightResp_BL_Full`.

A condensed overview would look like this:

```
condensed_dataset

       id Burden_Amount_BL        Akzeptanz_3_BL_r WeightResp_BL_Full
1    8371               NA Definitely will not use          1.1279761
2    4824                4     Definitely will use          0.9129661
3    5146                3                      NA          0.8846529
4   57169                3 Definitely will not use          1.5682342
5   12479                3   Probably will not use          0.3589912
6    3489                3                      NA          1.1799084
7      37                3   Probably will not use          1.2451010
8    9634               NA          Maybe will use          1.1470681
9     278                0   Probably will not use          1.2789439
10  84691                2 Definitely will not use          1.6766708
```

As there is missing data, I use MICE to impute it, leaving me with the imputed dataset object. (This is just exemplary, the real imputation is more complex and uses a much bigger dataset and a pre-specified predictor-matrix).

```
condensed_imp <- mice(condensed_dataset,m=10, maxit=10)
```

As I want to calculate an ANOVA with the imputed data, I could use `mi.anova(mi.res=imp, formula="Burden_Amount_BL ~ Akzeptanz_3_BL_r")`. As `mi.anova()` however, does not offer the ability to specify weights, I tried to create my own version and adapt it where needed, which lead me to the problem described above. The specific steps that are performed before using the `lapply()` would be these, basically creating a list of imputed data frames:

```
class(condensed_imp)
[1] "mids"
m <- condensed_imp$m
h1 <- list(rep("", m))
for (ii in 1:m) {
    h1[[ii]] <- as.data.frame(mice::complete(condensed_imp, 
        ii))
}
mi.list <- h1
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are passing the variable name for the weights, and not the variable itself?

Comment: Thanks for thinking about this! The reason was that I have a list of data frames and I wanted to refer to the specific variable in the currently used data frame. I edited the question to further clarify the structure of all related parts.
I'll think about it, however, as the weights are not imputed, so I might be able to pass the whole variable, then.

Answer (score 0):

Works here:

```r
condensed_f <- function (mi.list, formula, xyz = "WeightResp_BL_Full")  {
    lapply(mi.list, FUN = function(dat) {
        ## print(xyz)
        x <- rnorm(10)
        y <- rnorm(10)
        stats::lm( y~x, weight=get(xyz) )
        ## stats::lm(formula, data = dat, weight=get(xyz))
    })
}

mi.list <- list(1,2,3)
WeightResp_BL_Full <- runif(10)
foo <- condensed_f (mi.list=mi.list, formula="Burden_Amount_BL ~ Akzeptanz_3_BL_r")

stopifnot( length(foo) == 3 )
```

Could you showcase actually setting the WeightResp... variable to something? (though I doubt that explains it)

Comment: Thanks for thinking this through. I edited the question to clarify the structure of the data frame and its related variables. Does that help to better understand the issue?

Comment: I realized that you did not specify the `data` variable in the `stats::` line which got me thinking. Might it be possible that R searches for the `xyz`-variable within the dataset (`dat`)? Whereas I want it to search for the Variable that is specified in the string (`WeightResp_BL_Full`) assigned to `xyz` within the dataset. (That's why I thought it might be related to the environment()).

Comment: That's easily tested and most surely should not be the case. I'll have another look at your update!